# Interuniversal Teichmuller theory's applications

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Apart from a proof of the ABC conjecture -and its accepted consequences- are there applications of Mochizuki's IUT? In particular are there already widely accepted applications? Does it shed interesting light on known facts?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, no.

Comment: This question of whether there are applications beyond ABC & its known consequences was posed directly to Mochizuki at the recent Oxford workshop, and his answer was that he isn't aware of any at the present time.